# How is reactive programming different from observer design pattern

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming

Recently, I came to hear about reactive programming. People say that it solves many common issues like callback hell and supports streams; it is all about data flow. How does that affect me? Why should I care about this 'data flow' thing. I am really not sure about what, why and how of Reactive programming. I read about it on Google and found that it basically works on "react when some dependancy changes". I have an example of AngularJS scenario.

Example: if I have a list of items rendered on a page with ng-repeat and a form above it to accept more data from user which is finally pushed into the list and DOM is re-rendered automatically by AngularJS (of course using dirty checking in digest cycle).

So, we can see that dependancy of list on input form is being tracked and managed by AngularJS. So, this thing is happening perfectly in AngularJS too. Does this mean that AngularJS is reactive? I read on Wikipedia that reactivity can be found not only in web apps but in Excel spreadsheets or digital circuits too.

Can someone help me to understand it? How exactly reactivity compares with observer design pattern?

Comment: I think the concept you are talking about is all about maintaining your state in one place. This is clearly not the case with two way databinding as AngularJS requires the variable and value to be present in the controller. With reactive programming you would use a store that can be accessed from anywhere. So lets say you have a angular (2+) component, you would create a variable in the component that subscribes to this store for new values. And you can do this from anywhere inside your application, all the data comes from this one place. Can you see the difference? :-)

Comment: @user3492940 I understand this thing. I agree that reactive programming maintains single source of truth which AngularJS does not. But my question still is "How exactly reactivity compares with observer design pattern?" What exactly is reactive programming. Use of store to implement single source of truth is an aspect of it.

Comment: I can only speak from my experience with ngrx, the observer design pattern is part of this reactive programming library. Typically you would dispatch an action, and the reducer will process this action, which updates the store. In this case the reducer is listening to actions being dispatched, so the reducer is utilizes the observer design pattern in this case. It is observing for actions to be dispatched, and when a action is dispatched it will do some work to update the store(what work has to be done, that is up to you as you define the reducer logic).